# Xcode 11.3 - Archive succeeds but does not appear anywhere

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina

Running archive in my project in Xcode 11.3 (and 11.2.1 as well) on a fresh installation of Mac OS Catalina results in "Build Successful" but it does not appear in the organizer. My scheme is correctly configured with "Reveal Archive in Organizer" checked.

After searching I found others with this issue from past versions of Xcode who solved it by restarting Xcode/Cleaning/Removing Derived data - this is not working for me. I have also verified my Installation Path is accurately showing /Applications.

I AM able to archive the project using xcodebuild in the terminal and specifying custom paths for the resulting files - but this is not ideal. Any help or advice would be appreciated.